# Transition from the pro version to the free version of the plugin

Tags: plugins

I have a Polylang Pro version of the plugin, but I want to switch to a free one, because I can’t update the plugin because the license has ended, and I can’t buy a new one. Will everything be fine with my content, etc.?

Comment: You will likely loose some features, no more upgrades doesn't mean you need to downgrade to the free version (unless there is a security issue found)

Comment: I need to go. This is customer request

Comment: That's a question for the plugin's support. Plugin specific questions are off topic here.